# Automatic Telnet to cisco switches

Tags: vbscript, telnet, cisco

I have many switches that we backup every night. I need to create a job that will automatically backup the running config.

I am currently using this, but how can I use a list of server ip addresses instead of having to repeat the code.

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

Dim WshShell

set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.run "cmd.exe"

WScript.Sleep 1000

'Send commands to the window as needed - IP and commands need to be customized

'Step 1 - Telnet to remote IP'

WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 10.1.130.91 23"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000


'Step 2 - Issue Commands with pauses'

WshShell.SendKeys ("password")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys ("Enable")
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

WshShell.SendKeys ("password")
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

WshShell.SendKeys ("terminal length 0")
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

WshShell.SendKeys ("show running-config")
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

wshShell.SendKeys ("copy run tftp://10.1.211.53/file1.xls")
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500


wshShell.SendKeys ("10.1.211.53")
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

wshShell.SendKeys ("file1.xls")
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 2000


'Step 3 - Exit Command Window

WshShell.SendKeys "exit"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "exit"

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
```

Comment: While it's obvious this is some kind of Visual Basic script, it really help get the right audience for your question if you correctly tag the question with language tags, and/or environment tags as well. Please edit your question to update your tags. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I see IP addresses in 3 spots in the script. I see the first one is the telnet IP for the target router. What are the other 2 used for? Do these ever change, or do they remain the same? Need to know this before a loop can be setup.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replies. Sorry if I did not use correct tag I am new to this forum. This is the only ip that will change WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 10.1.130.91 23" ip addresses are:
10.10.130.91, 10.1.130.101 and so on Appreciate your help :-)

Comment: Hi Randy,
Yes that is correct. Thanks a lot it can wait. No rush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Just create a file named CiscoIPs.txt with all your IP address with a carriage return after each one. Avoid spaces at the end of the records.

```
10.2.2.23
10.4.5.23
10.5.7.23
```

The IP list should be in the same folder as the VBScript, but you can certainly change this by editing "strIPFile = "CiscoIPs.txt" at the top of the script. Let me know if you have any issues.

```
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell, strIPFile, objFSO, objFile, IPAddress

strIPFile = "CiscoIPs.txt"

On Error Resume Next

set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const ForReading =   1
Const ForWriting =   2
Const ForAppending = 8
Const ReadOnly =     1

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strIPFile, ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  IPAddress = objFile.ReadLine
  'WScript.Echo IPAddress
  WshShell.run "cmd.exe"

  WScript.Sleep 1000

  'Send commands to the window as needed - IP and commands need to be customized

  'Step 1 - Telnet to remote IP'

  WshShell.SendKeys "telnet " & IPAddress & " 23"

  WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
  WScript.Sleep 1000

  'Step 2 - Issue Commands with pauses'

  WshShell.SendKeys ("password")

  WScript.Sleep 1000

  WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

  WScript.Sleep 500
  WshShell.SendKeys ("Enable")
  WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
  WScript.Sleep 500

  WshShell.SendKeys ("password")
  WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
  WScript.Sleep 500

  WshShell.SendKeys ("terminal length 0")
  WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
  WScript.Sleep 500

  WshShell.SendKeys ("show running-config")
  WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
  WScript.Sleep 500

  WshShell.SendKeys ("copy run tftp://" & IPAddress & ".xls")
  WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
  WScript.Sleep 500

  WshShell.SendKeys ("10.1.211.53")
  WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
  WScript.Sleep 500

  WshShell.SendKeys ("file1.xls")
  WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
  WScript.Sleep 2000

  'Step 3 - Exit Command Window

  WshShell.SendKeys "exit"
  WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
  WScript.Sleep 500
  WshShell.SendKeys "exit"
  WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
Loop

objFile.Close
```

Comment: Lars, I forgot to mention. If you ever find yourself needing to create a Telnet script from scratch, this utility is the best I have seen. "Telnet Scripting Tool" Check out my answer on this posting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274914/how-to-write-an-output-of-a-vb-script-to-a-file/39280318#39280318