# How to write an output of a VB script to a file?

Tags: windows, shell, vbscript, telnet

I have a script which will output the values of certain commands to the terminal?Can anyone help me to modify the script to write the output to a file?

```
:: Open a Telnet window

start telnet.exe 192.168.1.1

:: Run the scrip

cscript SendKeys.vbs



set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.sleep 50 
OBJECT.SendKeys "Administrator{ENTER}" 
WScript.sleep 50 
OBJECT.SendKeys "admin{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50 
OBJECT.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

For i = 1 to 10
 i = i - 1
 OBJECT.SendKeys "voice profile list{ENTER}"
 WScript.sleep 5000
 OBJECT.SendKeys "system debug cpu{ENTER}"
  WScript.sleep 2000
 OBJECT.SendKeys "memm stats{ENTER}"
 WScript.sleep 5000
Next
```

Comment: That's not going to work. Use a `telnet` command that's actually scriptable (like [`plink`](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink)).

Answer (score 0):

The "Telnet Scripting Tool" is what you need. I have used it in the past, and it works great. http://support.moonpoint.com/downloads/windows/network/Telnet/tst10.php

And if I recall correctly, it also negates the issue of the script hanging if the window loses focus.

```
tst10.exe /r:script.txt /o:output.txt
```